# How to upgrade Spring boot 2.6 to 3.1.0 and get my SOAP CXFServlet services to work that used to work without problem?

Tags: java

I have an application in production with a module to publish WEB SOAP services, it is in java 11, spring Boot 2.6.0 and javax, when updating it to java 17, spring boot 3.1.0 and jakarta my configuration file that manually loads the Servlet stopped working, when checking the interface of the ServletRegistrationBean class, the above code cannot be used and throws the following exception:

Bound mismatch: The type CXFServlet is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter  of the type ServletRegistrationBean

I understand that it is about javax and jakarta incompatibility but I can't find documentation that I understand to do the update.

Usé la actualización automática de Eclipse 2023-3 y sólo quitó las clases del proyecto.

Can somebody help me?

I changed the POM of the parent project and the module project

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.ediweb.marte</groupId>
        <artifactId>marte</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>marte-soap-inovativos</artifactId>
    <name>marte-soap-inovativos</name>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <cxf.version>3.3.0</cxf.version>
        <jaxb.api.version>2.3.0</jaxb.api.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxws</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-ws-security</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-features-logging</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>    
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0-b180830.0359</version>
            
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ediweb.marte.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>marte-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${cxf.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-sources</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceRoot>${basedir}/src/main/java</sourceRoot>
                            <wsdlOptions>
                                <wsdlOption>
                                    <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/WSEdiWeb.wsdl</wsdl>
                                    <serviceName>WSEdiWeb</serviceName>
                                </wsdlOption>
                            </wsdlOptions>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>



import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;

import org.apache.cxf.Bus;
import org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBus;
import org.apache.cxf.feature.LoggingFeature;
import org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl;
import org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import com.ediweb.edi.wse.webservices.edi.WSEdiWebEndPoint;

/**
 * @author edgar
 *
 */
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Configuration
public class MarteSoapInovativosConfig {

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean<CXFServlet> dispatcherservlet() {
        return new ServletRegistrationBean<CXFServlet>(new CXFServlet(), "/edi-1wse-edi-1.0/*");
    }

    @Bean(name = Bus.DEFAULT_BUS_ID)
    public SpringBus springbus(LoggingFeature loggingfeature) {
        SpringBus cxfbus = new SpringBus();
        cxfbus.getFeatures().add(loggingfeature);
        return cxfbus;
    }

    @Bean
    public LoggingFeature loggingfeature() {

        LoggingFeature loggingfeature = new LoggingFeature();
        loggingfeature.setPrettyLogging(true);
        return loggingfeature;
    }
    
    @Bean
      public Endpoint endpoint(Bus bus, WSEdiWebEndPoint wsEdiWebEndPoint) {
        EndpointImpl endpoint = new EndpointImpl(bus, wsEdiWebEndPoint);
        endpoint.publish("/WSEdiWeb");
        return endpoint;
      }
}
```

Comment: you can start to change the version of CXF to 4.0.1 with Spring Boot 3 and Java 17, and tell me the result please.